# SQL Data to JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

```
LIST  Time   Status
  A     22:05   0
  B     22:10   1
  C     22:30   1
  A     22:40   0
  C     22:50   1
  B     22:60   1
```

The above table needs to be converted to below JSON format

```
[

{ "name": "A",
data: [ [22:05,0], 
        [22:40,0]
      ]
},
{ "name": "B",
data: [ [22:10,1], 
        [22:60,1]
      ]
}
{ "name": "C",
data: [ [22:30,1], 
        [22:50,1]
      ]
 }
]
```

The above is in a DataTable , now need to format the JSON,the below code does not give me in the same format.

```
  List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the data from your table and creating a custom class to represent the data that needs to be serialized.  You data would be represented in a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyType {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<List<string>> Data {get;set;}
}
```

Then you would need a method to parse through your DataTable.  Something like this might do it:

```
public List<MyType> ParseTable(DataTable dt) {
   var myTypes = new List<MyType>();
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();

   foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
      var name = dr[0];
      var time = dr[1];
      var status = dr[2]; 
      if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(dr[0]) {
        dictionary[name] = new List<List<string>>();
      }

      dictionary[name].Add(new List<string>{time, status});
   }

   foreach(var key = dictionary.Keys) {
      myTypes.Add(new MyType {Name = key, Data = dictionary[key]});
   }

   return myTypes;
}
```

Then use a JSON serializer like http://james.newtonking.com/json to handle the actual serialization of your object into JSON.

That would look something like this:

```
public string Serialize(List<MyType> myTypes) {
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTypes);
}
```

Please understand that this is freehand and off the cuff.  So it may not be optimal and may need some tweaking.  But this should get you where you are trying to go.

Comment: Thanks , I'm confused on extracting the data from the datatable above into this class .

Comment: When you serialize an object into JSON, the serializer will typically turn it into a dictionary of key-value pairs.  So if you want to model a JSON result into a type/class, you would choose the keys in the dictionary to be properties.  Then if you have any JSON lists that you need to create, you simply use a List<> to represent those items.

Comment: Thanks,can you provide a sample .I got the DataTable with the data mentioned above .Need to create this strcuture .Let me know

Comment: @Alfaromeo Updated my solution.  I think that should help.

Comment: Thanks you were patient throughout and in explaining the working. The solution works like a charm . BTW the first values is date/time datatype and the second integer .How to go about making this change as I see all are in string.

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with the JSON value.  JSON serialization of dates can get a little difficult.  It's easier to work with a string in that case.  And if you ever needed to deserialize the data, you can always call DateTime.Parse and int.Parse on string values.